# Measuring current from a digital pin with analogRead

Tags: arduino

I want to be able to check if some pieces of a puzzle is placed or not. To do this as easy as possible, I've set up 5 digital pins to output HIGH with `digitalWrite()`. The wires from the digital pins is connected to one analog pin each. Instead of a closed circuit, I have a gap for each piece of puzzle which is covered in aluminium foil.

The logic is that when the puzzle piece is placed, the circuit will be complete - and the Arduino will give some sort of output. Since I have a lot of pieces, I need some logic to test if each specific piece is placed or not.

I've tried to read the  output from the `digitalWrite()` with `analogRead()` and map the values of 0-1023 on a 0-100 scale. This gives me a high variation in readings, and sometimes a reading of 100 (1023) even though the circuit is not closed by the puzzle piece.

Is it possible to get a more precise reading that doesn't vary so much? So far I haven't used any resistance between the different pins.

Comment: Are you sure that the varying reading are not real? I.e. can you exclude a hardware problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you connecting to an analog pin?

Go digital all the way. Connect the digital pin to another digital pin, enable the pull-up resistors and then do a `digitalRead` on that pin.

You should get 1 if it's on and 0 if it's off.

Pretty simple, no?

I hope I helped.